# plymouth not showing image at startup

Tags: arch-linux, boot, startup, plymouth

I'm trying to follow the instructions to get a custom background working, when my Arch installation first boots.  I'm following the wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Plymouth#Installation

I installed plymouth-git

Added plymouth to hooks in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`: `HOOKS=(base udev plymouth ...)`

Added `MODULES=(i915)` (modules was empty before)

Disabled my display manager `systemctl disable lightdm`
enabled plymouth: `systemctl enable lightdm-plymouth`

First problem was that `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/theme/background-tile.png` didn't exist. So I created an image and used that.

Running:
# plymouthd
# plymouth --show-splash
# plymouth --quit
Showed a black screen with the text cursor thing.

`plymouth-set-default-theme -R spinner`

However upon reboot, the text is displayed as normal.

How do I fix this? I've been trying all morning

Comment: Never-mind following this video solved the problem. https://youtu.be/h36vtJzCJlg
Basically I had to add `splash` to grub boot